# DbDataAdapter with value from a db function

Tags: c#, sql, dataadapter

is it possible to do a tableadapter update with a datarow[]
and for a datetime column the value is set to a db function ea getdate(), userDefinedFunctionReturnDateTime() etc..

so not fixed values from a datarow[]

`INSERT INTO X(A,B,C)VALUES(1, '2015-01-01 00:00', 'name')`

but function values

`INSERT INTO X(A,B,C)VALUES(1, getdate(), 'name')`

something like `datarow.ItemArray[1] = "getdate()";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set the insert value based on the command your SQL database recognizes and it should work.

```
Ex: MySQL could use NOW()
SQL-Server could use GetDate()
```

all exactly as you have sampled.  The only thing is, you would NOT be using a parameter value, just build your insert statement with that fixed context INSTEAD of an actual parameter place-holder.

Is there a specific way you are building your insert statements?  or having them auto-generated somehow?

Comment: Does not completely work. When using the datarow.SetField(2, "getdate()"); i get a error "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.Couldn't store <getdate()> in TIME_STAMP Column.  Expected type is DateTime."

Comment: @JeroendeJong,  Is the "SetField" a user-defined function within SQL-Server or is it a function within C#.  If within SQL-Server, don't put quotes around your getDate() call.